# Gradle kotlin Unsupported method Dependencies.getAtoms()

Tags: android, gradle, kotlin, android-studio-3.0

Just started a new Android project with Studio 3.0 Canary 3 using kotlin and just trying to get it to do a gradle project sync. Currently failing with

```
Error:Unsupported method: Dependencies.getAtoms().
The version of Gradle you connect to does not support that method.
To resolve the problem you can change/upgrade the target version of Gradle you connect to.
Alternatively, you can ignore this exception and read other information from the model.
```

Anyone know what this means and how to get around it?

Probably just need to change the version of something.

gradle wrapper:

```
#Mon Jun 19 08:02:32 BST 2017
distributionBase=GRADLE_USER_HOME
distributionPath=wrapper/dists
zipStoreBase=GRADLE_USER_HOME
zipStorePath=wrapper/dists
distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-4.0-all.zip
```

project gradle

```
buildscript {
    ext.kotlin_version = '1.1.2-5'
    repositories {
        maven { url 'https://maven.google.com' }
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.0.0-alpha4'
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"

        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        maven { url 'https://maven.google.com' }
        jcenter()
        mavenCentral()
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

app gradle

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 25
    buildToolsVersion "25.0.3"
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "uk.me.mungorae.aircraft.aircraft"
        minSdkVersion 21
        targetSdkVersion 25
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    androidTestImplementation('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
    })
    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jre7:$kotlin_version"
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.4.0'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I just managed to fix this by updating to **Android Studio 3.0 Canary 4**.

You can download it at:
https://developer.android.com/studio/preview/index.html

Comment: Yep that seemed to fix it. Thanks.